# List with and grouping Drag and Drop

Tags: html, angularjs, jquery-ui

I have list of items. each item has date and few more properties.
I created a grouping by date using the next code:

//Grouping feature

```
var indexedparts = [];

//create a groupBy Scheduled date
$scope.groupbyScheduledDateFilter = function(part) {
    var partIsNew = indexedparts.indexOf(part.groupedScheduleTime) == -1;
    if (partIsNew) {
        indexedparts.push(part.groupedScheduleTime);
    }
    return partIsNew;
}

$scope.scheduledDatesToFilter = function() {
    indexedparts = [];
    return $scope.scheduledParticipants;
}
```

here is my view code:

```
  <ul class="list-unstyled zero-margin" ng-repeat="time in scheduledDatesToFilter() | filter: groupbyScheduledDateFilter">
      <li ng-bind="time.groupedScheduleTime" class="color-bg-lighter-white-smoke manage-date-groupby"></li>
      <ul buildit-sortable="onItemDroppedInScheduledList" class="list-group manage-plan-draggable-list zero-margin" ng-model="scheduledParticipants" connect-with="planned" id="scheduledList">
          <li class="list-group-item hand-cursor" ng-repeat="part in scheduledParticipants | filter:searchScheduledParticipants | filter: {groupedScheduleTime: time.groupedScheduleTime}">
```

The grouping works perfectly until I drag items from another list and drop them into the "grouped" list. 
When the list is finished rendered it seems like:

[image: valid grouped list]

but when I drop the first item, the grouping does not get's updated:

[image: invalid list]

as you can see, the new item does not get inserted into a grouping container and the 2 items that already located inside the grouped list, get duplicated and sits with the new item outside any group.

I assume that the filters which create the date grouping, doesn't run again. I need in some way tell angular "please refresh you ng-repeat" or something like "when you insert new item, do it using the filters". how can I do it?

If my while approach is wrong and you've better design, I would be happy to hear.
Thanks
Ofir

Comment: This might help: http://plnkr.co/edit/kFwqtlqGd4qpFRxWMQrj?p=preview

Comment: this example does not includes grouping - it's not my case